# Add column with number of specific values within group in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
ID       SUB_ID     Action  
1         A          Open
1         A          Download
1         A          Close
1         B          Open
1         B          Search
1         B          Download
1         B          Close
2         AA          Open
2         AA          Download
2         AA          Close
2         BB          Open
2         BB          Search
2         BB          Filter
2         BB          Close
3         C           Open
3         C           Search
3         C           Filter
3         C           Close
```

I want to get table with ID and number of SUB_ID per ID and number of "Download" in column Action within one SUB_ID. So, desired result is:

```
ID       SUB_ID_n     Download_n 
1         2            2
2         2            1
3         1            0
```

How could i do that?

Comment: What if e.g. in ID1 there was one Download for SUB_ID A and two Downloads for SUB_ID B? Do you mean rather the number of downloads within one ID?

Answer (score 0):

Count number of unique values using `n_distinct` and sum over logical values to calculate rows with `Action == 'Download'`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(SUB_ID_n = n_distinct(SUB_ID, na.rm = TRUE), 
            Download_n = sum(Action == 'Download'))

#    ID SUB_ID_n Download_n
#  <int>    <int>      <int>
#1     1        2          2
#2     2        2          1
#3     3        1          0
```

---

In `data.table` this can be written as :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(SUB_ID_n = uniqueN(SUB_ID, na.rm = TRUE), 
              Download_n = sum(Action == 'Download')), ID]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), SUB_ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "AA", "AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "C", 
"C", "C", "C"), Action = c("Open", "Download", "Close", "Open", 
"Search", "Download", "Close", "Open", "Download", "Close", "Open", 
"Search", "Filter", "Close", "Open", "Search", "Filter", "Close"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Comment: thanks, when i use your second method in case of there is NA in SUB_ID it counts it. Is it possible to make it not to count NA?

Comment: @french_fries you can use `na.rm = TRUE` in both `uniqueN` and `n_distinct` to ignore `NA` values. See updated answer.